# Eigenvalues of rank one matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

For a given vector $v=(v_1,v_2,\dots, v_n)$ consider the matrix $B=v^tAv$ where $A=(a_{ij})_{i,j=1,\dots,n}$ with $a_{ij}=1$ i.e.

$$
B=\begin{pmatrix} v_1v_1&v_1v_2& \dots & v_1v_n\\ v_2v_1&v_2v_2& \dots & v_2v_n\\\dots&\dots&\dots&\dots\\v_nv_1&v_nv_2& \dots & v_nv_n\end{pmatrix}
$$

If for some $k$, $v_k\neq 0$ then it follows that $B$ has rank $1$. Is there a direct way of finding the kernel and eigenvalues of $B$?

Comment: Isn't $B=vv^T$, considering $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$? I don't see how the matrix $A$ is needed, or even how the multiplication was done ($v^TAv$ is a matrix given by $(1\times n) \cdot (n\times n) \cdot (n\times 1)$, so it's a scalar... because it's a quadratic form...). Feel free to comment

Comment: Note that this doesn't imply that @voldemort's answer is wrong. But I don't see how $A$ is needed to do the calculations...

Comment: @cjferes: I think He is viewing $v$ as $(1 \cross n)$ and not as $n \cross 1$.

Comment: @cjferes It's just different notation.

Comment: Sorry for insisting, but if $v$ were $(1\imes n)$, then $v^TAv=(n\times1)\cdot(n\times n)\cdot(1\times n)$, and that's not allowed... I know this doesn't change the answer at all, but I still don't see the need of $A$. The same reasoning can be done using $v^TV$. Anyway, thanks for answering!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $B$ has rank $1$ which implies that $n-1$ eigenvalues are $0$ and $B$ has only $1$ non zero eigenvalue. The non zero eigenvalue can be computed bu a little trick: sum of eigenvalues equals the trace, and so the only nonzero eigenvalue is the trace of $B$.

$Tr(B)=Tr(v^tAv)=Tr(vv^tA)$. Note that $vv^t=v_1^2+..v_n^2$. Now the computation is really easy :).

Comment: For a basis of the kernel what would you suggest to do?

Comment: @Test123: The ker has dim $n-1$. Find out an eigenvector corresponding to the only non zero eigenvalue, say $y$ and then Ker$T$ is $y\perp$